# Is it correct to say 'now onwards'?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

When mentioning time period, is it correct to use the phrase "now onwards"? can we use 'onwards' after 'now'?  or should we use only 'now on'?

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic expression is "**from now on**". As [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=from%20now%20on%2C%20from%20now%20onwards&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfrom%20now%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrom%20now%20onwards%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfrom%20now%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrom%20now%20onwards%3B%2Cc0) shows, 'from now onwards' has been used very rarely in comparison.

Example:

> We will do this from now on.

Other similar expressions include:

- We will do this **in future**.
- We will do this **from now on**.

There is also an expression "going forward" (eg "we will do this *going forward*") but this is disliked by many as it is considered a meaningless corporate buzzphrase.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was a great learning!